# Regression coefficient model

Tags: regression, statistical-significance

Suppose a researcher studying the incidence of cardiovascular disease estimates a regression model by including information on each person’s cholesterol level (as an independent explanatory variable).  If the researcher fails to also include information on whether the person is a smoker, will the estimated regression coefficient on cholesterol be biased?  If so, will the bias be positive or negative?

Comment: Is this for some subject?

Answer (score 0):

Are cholesterol level and smoking correlated? If they are not, then your regression coefficient will not be biased. Otherwise you have so called omitted variable bias:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias